# PHP pass data beteen two scripts on the same page

Tags: php

How can I pass data from PHP code above the HTML to the PHP code below the HTML? I need the PHP code below the HTML since the code being run will not run before the HTML.

Top PHP:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['amount'] = null;


    if(isset($_POST['moneyBTN'])){

    $pack = $_POST['package'];
      if($pack == "1"){
        $_SESSION['amount'] = 600;

        $data_amount = 600;
        $data_name = "Example1";
      }
       if($pack == "2"){
        $_SESSION['amount'] = 1000;

        $data_amount = 1000;
        $data_name = "Example2";
      }
       if($pack == "3"){
        $_SESSION['amount'] = 1300;

        $data_amount = 1300;
        $data_name ="Example3"; 
      }

    }
    ?>
```

The PHP below the HTML:

```
<div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Desc</p>

        <iframe width="0" height="0" border="0px solid white" 
style="display:none" name="target1" id="target1"></iframe>

          <form action="shop.php" method="post" target="target1" >

        <div class="form-group input" >

                <select name="package" class="form-control" id="select">

                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>


                </select>
              </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="moneyBTN" 
    value="Continue">
        <div>
         </form>
        <div  ">
          <form action="shop.php" method="post">
          <script
          src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          data-amount=<?php echo $data_amount;?>
          data-name=<?php echo $data_name;?>
          data-description="Buy"
          data-
image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
          data-locale="auto">
          </script>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

The following is the php code:

```
<?php
      $amount = $_SESSION['amount'];
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_testxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

      $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      "amount" => $amount,
      "currency" => "usd",
      "description" => "Buy",
      "source" => $token,
      ));

    ?>
```

Currently, this is not working. How can I make it work? Based on the number selected, the amount has a different value. This value determines how much money is inputted into the Stripe code.

Comment: Please paste the whole code with html part.

Comment: @meta I have added the code

Comment: @apaul: Check if it works for you.

Comment: It's still not helpful - we don't know what you mean by below/above php. Is it in one file? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your inputs, I made this script.

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['amount'] = null;
$data_amount = null;
$data_name = null;

if(isset($_POST['moneyBTN'])){
    $pack = $_POST['package'];
    if($pack == 1){
       $_SESSION['amount'] = 600;
       $data_amount = 600;
       $data_name = "Example1";
    }
    if($pack == 2){
       $_SESSION['amount'] = 1000;
       $data_amount = 1000;
       $data_name = "Example2";
    }
    if($pack == 3){
       $_SESSION['amount'] = 1300;
       $data_amount = 1300;
       $data_name ="Example3"; 
    }
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Desc</p>            
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
                <div class="form-group input" >
                    <select name="package" class="form-control" id="package">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="moneyBTN" name="moneyBTN" value="Continue">
            </form>
            <iframe width="150px" height="50px" style="border:solid 1px #fff;" name="target1" id="target1">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['amount']." ".$data_amount." ".$data_name;?>
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['amount']." ".$data_amount." ".$data_name; ?>
            <form action="shop.php" method="post">
                <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" 
                    data-key="pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    data-amount=<?php echo $data_amount;?>
                    data-name=<?php echo $data_name;?>
                    data-description="Buy"
                    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                    data-locale="auto">
                </script>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>





<?php   
$amount = $_SESSION['amount'];
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_testxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $amount,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "description" => "Buy",
    "source" => $token,
));
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Divyang, Thanks for your help. I have updated my question to add more code.

Answer (score 2):

If both code is on the same page (i.e. in the same PHP file), then variables should be able to be used over many PHP code blocks, as most PHP variables have the same scope.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

If we see a full version of the code, this will help in finding the cause of the problem.